# $applyAsync - provided function is not called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Does anyone know what can be the reason that function provided to applyAsync is not called? There is no error in console... :/

```
console.log('regApplyAsync');
$rootScope.$applyAsync(function() {
    console.log('applyThis');
});
```

console output:

```
regApplyAsync
```

EDIT: I cannot reproduce it again, I was just astonished how can such case be possible. I was debugging it for a while and it disappeared. In my opinion there should not be the case that the function is not called. Right?

Comment: what is the problem, it seems fine for me http://plnkr.co/edit/ohP3QskUimrlQiNFWiyc?p=preview

Comment: Yeah.. I cannot reproduce it again, I was just astonished how can such case be possible. I was debugging it for a while and it disappeared. In my opinion there should not be the case that mentioned function is not called. Right?

Comment: No..it won't happen..may be the possibility is you are not using lower version than `angular-1.3` which doesn't have `$applyAsync` method in it.but that should throw an error in consoel..

Comment: My angular version is 1.4.3, and there was no error, so I was even more supprised..